# Java Android - HttpURLConnection - Response Code 400 on Android 4.x.x

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am using the following code:

```
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive","false");
        String content;
        mainURL += "&fingerprint=" + Build.FINGERPRINT + "&devicename=" + "" + "&devicemodel=" + Build.MANUFACTURER + " - " + Build.MODEL;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(mainURL);
            HttpURLConnection urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlconn.setConnectTimeout(HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
            urlconn.setReadTimeout(HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
            urlconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlconn.connect();

            int responseCode = urlconn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                content = readStream(urlconn.getInputStream());
            }else{
                content = "error";
            }

            urlconn.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "error";
        }

        return content;
```

This works fine on Android 6.x.x and Android 7.x.x but on Android 4.4.2 it's returning http response code 400. Is this problem maybe being caused because of this:

`mainURL += "&fingerprint=" + Build.FINGERPRINT + "&devicename=" + "" + "&devicemodel=" + Build.MANUFACTURER + " - " + Build.MODEL;`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint after your `try` to check which url gets called from the different Android versions?

Comment: @Signo my problem is, that I haven't got an android 4 device. This issue was reported to me from an unknown user that's why I am asking here.

Comment: Ok I understand! Btw, if you're using Android Studio, I think you should be able to download a working emulator for version 4.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

`Build` is not working on Android 4.x.x that's why HttpURLConnection didn't work either.